# Usage API Error in intellji

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8, java-7

I'm recently switching  into Intellij 2017 IDEA from Eclipse.

in eclipse when create a  new Java Project we can define witch version of JDK imported to project.for example i'm installed JDK version 1.8 (or 8) but in eclipse when i define new project I can chose witch version of jdk imported to my project. thats totally work fine. by in Intellij IDE  I added JDK version 1.8 to Project.  some of methods in my project work with JDK 1.7 and don't work in version 1.8.

problem here i got this error "usage of api documented as since 1.7". i know it just to  add JDK 1.7 but i wont to installan older version of JDK into my machine. How Can I fix This Problem??

this solution do'snt work when I decrease the level of JDK  in  my Project.
File > Project Structure > Project Settings > Modules > your Module name > Sources > Language Level >

also this line of code is got me Error is here:

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
```

and when i'm using this method:
`Files.isSymbolicLink`

thanks.

Comment: hmm so in eclipse you were able to target java 7 without installing it ?

Comment: wouldn't? when create a  java project must chose version of jdk add to project... and it can  less version of jdk installed into your machine

Answer (score 0):

in "project-structure" - change project or module's language level to 7.

and in setting-build-compiler-java -compiler, change bytecode version also to 7

Comment: thanks for giving me a solution, but it doesn't work.

Comment: do you know about  this method "Files.isSymbolicLink(some thing)"
in witch version work fine?
i'm gotting error since work with JDK version 1.8